# In MySQL, what are the pros and cons of these two approachs to junction tables?

Tags: sql, mysql

Just figured out that it appears the only way to map many-to-many relationship is via a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). Looking for advice on the pros and cons of the two approaches I've come up with.

### SAMPLE_DATABASE:

```
table_01
-- table_01_id (pk)
-- table_01_data

table_02
-- table_02_id (pk)
-- table_02_data
```

### Junction table (1)

```
junction_id (pk)
table_01_id (fk)
table_02_id (fk)
```

### Junction table (2)

```
table_01_id (pk)
table_02_id (pk)
```

Guessing **Junction table (2)** is the way to go, but interested in knowing why.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do link tables need a meaningless primary key field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843222/do-link-tables-need-a-meaningless-primary-key-field)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647797/what-would-it-mean-if-i-change-the-identifying-relationship-from-this-part-of-a-d

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thanks, so it better to delete the question, or let it be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The junction_id (pk) in Junction table (1) is meaningless.  It's a waste to have it, so don't.

Comment: While meaningless to the schema, it enforces an arbitrary physical write order for the table. Composite keys have some extra complexity involved in inserts and B+-tree balancing. On the whole, though, you should use two columns as a non-clustered PK and only add a clustered identity/sequence column if you start running into I/O problems caused by index maintenance issues.

Comment: @Jeremiah Peschka: Great, thanks -- that was the info I was looking for, and guessed was the answer too.

Comment: @Jeremiah- But chances are you would want a composite index and unique constraint on `table_01_id, table_02_id` anyway which would still have to be maintained.

Comment: @Martin - that's correct, but maintaining B+-trees in index supported tables is, IIRC, much faster than maintaining B+-trees on heap tables. MySQL attempts to skirt this problem by adding an arbitrary clustering column if you don't provide one AND you mark your PK as non-clustered. Either way, marking your PK (a unique, composite index in this case) as non-clustered in MySQL is a perfectly safe thing to do... until they change the behavior without telling us.

Answer (score 2):

See [Do link tables need a meaningless primary key field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843222/do-link-tables-need-a-meaningless-primary-key-field)