# MSSQL Delete query on a table with foreign key

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, foreign-key-relationship

I have 2 tables

t1 - Categories
Id
Name

t2 - Products
Id
Name
CategoryId

I have a foreign key and it`s working but when I want to run a Delete query (for example O keep getting an error because of the foreign key.)

ths is my code:

```
        protected void dlCategory_DeleteCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string Id = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1")).Text;
    string SQL = "DELETE FROM Categories WHERE PrimaryKey=@ID;";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Id);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    BindDL();
}
```

If I remove the foreign key it`s working just fine!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can't run a query with the Primary Key as a parameter, You need to do the long handed way.

```
string SQL = "DELETE FROM Categories WHERE PrimaryKey= '$Cat_ID';";
```

Similar answer here 
[Mysql Select record where PRIMARY key = x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788451/mysql-select-record-where-primary-key-x)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to remove a record from Categories, but that record cannot be deleted because it is in use by the Products table.

If you have a category of 'clothes' and a product of 't-shirt' that is given the category  of clothes, then removing the category would give you a data error, as the database is now inconsistent.

This is expected functionality. You can amend SQL Server to use cascading deletes, so all connected records are also deleted, but use this carefully.

Comment: I created  a new Category, it`s not used by any Product. Anyway, can you give me an example of how cascading deletes are working ?! Thanks

Comment: Are both tables empty, apart from the record you are trying to delete?

Comment: Cascading deletes would delete any products that have the Category ID that is being deleted from the Category table.
These are set in the database relationship between the tables. In the properties, under the 'INSERT And UPDATE Specification' section, set the 'Delete Rule' to 'Cascade'.