# JPA : Ensure that children entities are owned by entity's parent entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

So let's say you have

```
class Employee {
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn
 private Department department;
}

class Department {


}

class EmployeeGroup {

   @OneToMany
   @JoinTable
   private Set<Employee> employees;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn
   private Department department;
}
```

How would you ensure that all employees from a specific group, are from the same Department as the EmployeeGroup's department ?

I've tried with array of `@JoinColumn` within `@JoinTable`... but It seems that hibernate can't share in link table the same column for fk_department_id in both Foreign keys.

What I expect to get is : a link table with three columns, fk_group_id, fk_employee_id, fk_department_id, and 2 FK (department_id, employee_Id) to employee table, and (department_id, group_id) to emp_group table.

Is it possible without ComplexPK?

*Business case : you have two departments, IT and Finance, 3 groups, Java Group and .NET group which belong to IT department, HR group which belong to Finance department. You have 5 employees. all of them are in IT department, two of them also in Java group, two of them in .NET group, and one of them is an internship member which does not belong to any groups yet, but it is in the same department. Now I want to ensure that when you take 1 employee from IT department and say employee.getGroups(), all of them are also IT groups and the collection does not contain accidentally the HR group.*

Comment: Why would you want to ensure it on the database mapping level? That's a business rule that `EmployeeGroup` should be validated against before you try to persist anything

Comment: I wouldn't want to end up with incorrect mapping in DB. `EmployeeGroup` is a group of `Employee`s within one `Department`

Comment: This is perfectly possible in SQL. You have a linked Table with two FK with two columns each. This may require you to have Unique Keys in both Employee(id, department_id) and EmployeeGroup(id, department_id), but I just try to figure out how to represent this in JPA.

Comment: I never said it was impossible, just that it wasn't a good idea. Your schema is redundant, in that the employee's department information is duplicated, since it is present in both the link table and the employee table.

Comment: @crizzis you may sometimes work with a legacy database!

Comment: @O.Bard Fair enough, but the question asked was 'how would you ensure that all employees from a specific group, are from the same Department as the EmployeeGroup's department?' and not 'how do I map this legacy db schema?'

Comment: Why would you think that this is a legacy db schema ? how would you build the tables then ? The use case is simple...you have a lot of employees they are mandatory  in one department...but they also can be optionally in a lot of groups within the same department....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would you ensure that all employees from a specific group, are from the same Department as the EmployeeGroup's department?

If you want to make this restriction in Hibernate/JPA level which is also the DB level you need to make this restriction with a **composite primary key**, the primary key will hold both the `DepartmentPK` and the `EmployeeGroupPK` for every `Employee`.

> is it possible without ComplexPK?

The short answer is **No**, because only a composite primary key can provide these restrictions on all sides foreach `Employee`.

Otherwise you will keep your mapping as it is and make these restrictions in the business level.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular scenario why are you making relationship between employee and department classes?(I don't think it is a well normalized design too)

Why don't you just specify the below mentioned relations:
 1. One To Many relation in EmployeeGroup with Employeee 
 2. Many To One relation in EmployeeGroup with Department
 3. Many To One relation in Employee with EmployeeGroup
 4. One To Many relation in Department with EmployeeGroup

In this way, you can derive the department of an employee via its employee group and make sure that employees belonging to same employee group belong to same department.

Comment: The use case is simple...you have a lot of employees they are mandatory in one department...but they also can be optionally in a lot of groups within the same department....

Comment: So when the employee is not in any groups, how would you guess the department ?

Comment: Business case : you have two departments, IT and Finance, 3 groups, Java Group and .NET group which belong to IT department, HR group which belong to Finance department.  You have 5 employees. all of them are in IT department, two of them also in Java group, two of them in .NET group, and one of them is an internship member which does not belong to any groups yet, but it is in the same department. Now I want to ensure that when you take 1 employee from IT department and say employee.getGroups(), all of them are also IT groups and the collection does not contain accidentally the HR group.

Comment: " one of them is an internship member which does not belong to any groups yet, but it is in the same department. "

For this scenario you can easily handle by adding a group Intern IT(though it is not one of the groups of your business scenario) with department as IT. See it is the technical implementation and it depends completely on developer how to proceed with the implementation. .

Answer (score 0):

> How would you ensure that all employees from a specific group, are
>   from the same Department as the EmployeeGroup's department?

You can ensure that by making a relation between `Employee` and `EmployeeGroup` which has an association with `Department` and remove `Department<-->Employee` association, so to know which `Department` an `Employee` belongs to, you should navigate through `EmplpoyeeGroup` association.

> So when the employee is not in any groups, how would you guess the
>   department?

You can solve this by using a default group for each `Department`, so every `Employee` that is not affected to a group, must belong to his `Department`'s default group, so your mapping will be :

```
public class Employee{    
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EmployeeGroup_id")
    private EmployeeGroup employeeGroup; 

    ...
}

public class Department{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<EmployeeGroup> employeeGroup;        

    @OneToOne(optional = false, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DefaultEmployeeGroup_id")
    private EmployeeGroup defaultEmployeeGroup;

    ...
}

class EmployeeGroup {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employeeGroup")
    private Set<Employee> employees;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name ="department"_id)
    private Department department;

    ...
}
```

This solution may remove a redundant association between `Employee` and `Department` and will enforce the business rule on the database side.

**The Second solution:**

Is checking integrity between `Employee`'s group and his `Department` in your code, by checking the `setDepartment(Department)` and `setEmployeeGroup(EmployeeGroup)` in your `Employee` class. 
Here the business rule won't be checked in the database layer (if other application uses the same database).

**Note:**

- I don't [prefer a composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737190/composite-primary-key-or-not) for sake of simplicity unless I don't have a choice.
- I don't think [it's a good idea](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) to use `@JoinTable` with `@OneToMany` for `EmployeeGroup.employees` field, Hibernate will create a separate table for `EmployeeGroup-->Employee` association.

Hope it helps.