# How to design a database in the way that each class has one teacher and one TAs?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I have 2 tables:

```
User(LoginID,Password,Email,UserType) --  Primary key(LoginID)
Class(CourseCode, Semester,Year,ClassTime,ProID) -- Primary key(CourseCode, Semester,Year) -- Foreign key(ProID)
```

UserType can be Teacher, Teaching Assistant(TA) or Student.
Now I dont know where I can add TA attribute so that one class has one TA and one Teacher. I am thinking about putting TAID into User table as a foreign key, so that would be:

```
Class(CourseCode, Semester,Year,ClassTime,ProID,TAID)
```

But I'm not sure it is right or not. Because when I want to get teacher and TA's Name who teach a specific course, it does not work. I've tried the query below:

```
SELECT dbo.[User].Name
FROM  dbo.Class INNER JOIN
           dbo.[User] ON dbo.Class.ProID = dbo.[User].LoginID AND dbo.Class.TAID = dbo.[User].LoginID
WHERE CrsCode=@CrsCode and Semester=@Semester and Year=@Year
```

**Question:** Does anyone have any idea for this problem? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I wrote:

```
alter proc SelectFacultyNameByID
@CrsCode nvarchar(5),
@Semester nvarchar(20),
@Year int
as
SELECT 
u1.Name as Teacher,
u2.Name as Assistant
FROM
dbo.Class c
JOIN [User] u1
 ON c.ProID = u1.LoginID
JOIN [User] u2
ON c.TAID = u2.LoginID
WHERE 
c.CrsCode = @CrsCode 
AND c.Semester = @Semester 
AND c.Year = @Year
```

But it does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, most straighforward solution would be for a `Class` to reference the `User` twice to implement a teacher and TA. So - two fields, I recommend TeacherID and AssistandID.

In the other direction, `User` should have a reference to `Class` to implement a class-membership.

However, I think your `User` table should be `Student`.
Another thing is you should have another table for teachers, like `Teacher`, where you would stuff your teachers and MAYBE TA's. It depends if the fields that accompany your teacher/TA are the same. Otherwise there should be another table `TeacherAssistant` or `Assistant`.

At last, if you have to have some table where all your users in database reside and those are teachers, TA's and students, feel free to have `Users` table, but there should be a reference to it from `Teachers`, `Assistants` and `Students`.

To sum it up, you should probably have these tables to cover your requirements:

- Class (ID, TeacherID, AssistantID, ...)
- Teacher (ID, Name, ..., UserID)
- Assistant (ID, Name, ..., UserID)
- Student (ID, Name, ClassID, ..., UserID)
- User (ID, Name, ...)

Another thing - in contemporary applications it is easier to have ID as PK. I believe your PK is a valid PK candidate, but it's easier (and is becomming a convention) to have autoincrement/identity/sequence ID as a PK in your table, and the real PK candidate as a unique key. For more info, [see this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159087/composite-primary-keys-versus-unique-object-id-field). SO, correct me if I'm wrong, but it really makes my ORM (Entity Framework) happy.

**EDIT**

In your current solution, if following...

```
SELECT u.Name
FROM
  dbo.Class c
  JOIN [User] u 
    ON c.ProID = u.LoginID
WHERE 
  c.CrsCode = @CrsCode 
  AND c.Semester = @Semester 
  AND c.Year = @Year
```

...means all teacher names of *such* classes in *that* year/semester, then...

```
SELECT u.Name
FROM
  dbo.Class c
  JOIN [User] u 
    ON c.ProID = u.LoginID
    AND c.TAID = u.LoginID
WHERE 
  c.CrsCode = @CrsCode 
  AND c.Semester = @Semester 
  AND c.Year = @Year
```

...means for *such* classes in *that* year/semester, find all classes that have same teacher AND teacher assistant and output their names.

You probably need:

```
SELECT 
  Teacher = u1.Name,
  Assistant = u2.Name
FROM
  dbo.Class c
  JOIN [User] u1
    ON c.ProID = u1.LoginID
  JOIN [User] u2
    ON c.TAID = u2.LoginID
WHERE 
  c.CrsCode = @CrsCode 
  AND c.Semester = @Semester 
  AND c.Year = @Year
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I have thought about that but my system is very simple. Users can login to the system. If they are students, they can see their grades. If they are Teachers/Teaching Assistants, they can add grades. If they are admins, they can manage login account and Class list. So, if I create 3 separate tables(Teacher, Assistant and Student), It would be complicated and not necessary. However, is it wrong if I just add AssistantID to the Class table as a foreign key of User table?

Comment: It is not wrong, as a matter of fact it's completely valid. However, what if your student of class#1 is a TA of class#2? Will you get confused when you see your own query in a few months? If it looks right to you, it's right to me as well ;)

Comment: Actually, to make it easy, I just assume that a TA cannot be a student, even thought it is not practical.:)

Comment: it's kind of weird, when I executed it as a query, it worked. But I saved it as a procedure and executed it. it showed nothing.@@

Comment: I teach at a university. One of the professors took my class. How does that work in your schema?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: whose schema, OP's or mine? In mine, you just update Class.TeacherID of a particular class, for any class you like.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: If you have read all of the correspondence between OP and me (see comment 2 and 3) you would have understood why was the solution simplified. But it supports this case partially: your professor would stay the same User, just a new Student that references it should be added.

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić Do you know the solution that when I ran your query, it worked perfectly, but I wrote it as a procedure and ran it, it didnot work?

Comment: @TungPham: I've noticed that, but I never saw that before. Are you sure your nvarchar(5) and nvarchar(20) parameters have proper types?