# Database Design Schema for Any New Project?

Tags: database, database-design

I need to know about **Database design for any new projects?**

- What are the **Database (Advance) concepts and standards** used for Database Design?
- How to **Analyse** Database design schema?

I am new to database design.i'm looking for best practice on designing database schema for any Project.Can you please suggest me for this or is there any reference links or books for database design?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database Design Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387339/database-design-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

i am using the following book for my reference to create database schema, so i refer the link for you also

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Relational_Database_Design

Comment: That is a horrible mess.